# jQuery error text not appending

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've this code for simple tagging system using PHP and JS. Its followed by a `%` sign, when i type in the tag followed by the `%` the tag comes but it dosent append in the textarea after I select it eg, I type `%abc`, abc links comes in the displaybox for selecting the tag  but when i click it nothing happens.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function()
{## Heading ##

    var start=/%/ig;
    var word=/%(\w+)/ig;

    $("#story").live("keyup",function() 
    {
        var content=$(this).val();
        var go= content.match(start);
        var name= content.match(word);
        var dataString = 'searchword='+ name;

        if(go.length>0)
        {
            $("#msgbox").slideDown('show');
            $("#display").slideUp('show');
            $("#msgbox").html("Type the name of someone or something...");
            if(name.length>0)
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "boxsearch.php",
                    data: dataString,
                    cache: false,
                    success: function(html)
                    {
                        $("#msgbox").hide();
                        $("#display").html(html).show();
                    }
                });
            }
        }
        return false();
    }); 
    $(".addname").live("click",function() 
    {
        var username=$(this).attr('title');
        var old=$("#story").html();
        var content=old.replace(,''); 
        $("#story").html(content);
        var E="<a class='blue' contenteditable='false' href='#'>"+username+"</a>";
        $("#story").append(E);
        $("#display").hide(); 
        $("#msgbox").hide();
        $("#story").focus();
    });

});
</script>
```

Comment: what error text is not appending? also what jquery version are you using?

Comment: tag is not coming in text area as a link
and im using jq 1.4.2

Comment: You should give us more insight if you want some help. Place console.log(your statement) at several places in your code. It would give us an idea of what's been processed. I have no idea what start and word return, while it is crucial to figure out.

Comment: What does ## Heading ## refer to? It is not properly commented.

Comment: you want a link in a textarea?? i dont think thats possible

Comment: i need to start a tagging system for my website in whch user post status with tags
and ## is just a comment when i was using a div instead of textarea
it was working here is a link to the tutorial i saw about this tagging system http://www.9lessons.info/2010/08/tag-friends-with-jquery-ajax-and-php.html

Comment: `textarea` cannot display links. Only text. Use Div instead.

Comment: then how shall i insert it into my db as a form

Comment: You can manually set data with the `$.POST` function. Just write your own form submit handler.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to display links in a textarea, you cant.

You should use a DIV for that matter.

As for the data to be sent to the DB, you could always put the contents of the DIV in a variable, and send it through ajax.

e.g.

```
<div id="data"><a href="textlink">testlink here</a></div>
```

In javascript:

```
var contentData = $('#data').html();
```

send this as a property through AJAX.